# Is it possible to test In App Billing in an Android App connected to and running from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, android-studio, in-app-billing

I'm building an Android App and integrating In App Billing.

I'm using the IabHelper class recommended by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html).

Fetching available products' information such as price using IabHelper's `queryInventoryAsync` method works properly (I get product / price information for the products I set up in Google Play Developer Console).

When testing purchase of a "managed" product I get two errors.

The first error occurs when I tap the "buy" button to buy a product I've just successfully retrieved pricing info for, and I'm presented with an alert from Google Play that says, "Error: This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information".

Googling this yields some suggestions that if the version number of the apk uploaded to Google Play is different from that of the apk I'm testing in differ, errors like this will occur. What is perplexing though is that I'm never notified of the purchase attempt failure after this alert is shown (and after I click okay).

This yields a second error when I tap on the "buy" button again to re-attempt purchase. The App crashes because IabHelper doesn't allow two async operations to be active at a time (the first failed attempt is never cancelled because the App is never alerted to failure, Google please read this).

Question 1: Should I be doing something differently that would cause the first unsuccessful purchase async operation to be cancelled (and alert the App so it can respond)? Obviously I will make sure the version numbers are in sync, but this seems like a bug regardless. The operation should never be allowed to not be cancelled upon failure.

Question 2: In general, is it possible to test in-app billing while running in debug mode from Android Studio? Ie can I connect my device, hit "run in debug" in Android Studio, and step through the code using break points? Or can in-app billing only be tested when not connected to Android Studio / the debugger? (This would be sort of insane if it's not possible but a few things I've read suggest that this is the case).

Thanks in advance for any tips!

**Edit: It turns out that when I install the same apk on the device that I uploaded to Google Play purchase works just fine. But the question remains: can you not test in-app billing while attached to the android studio debugger?**

Answer (score 1):

Except for the static purchase test items, you are generally no longer able to test in-app billing features while in debug mode. You have to use a release version of the app and complete the app setup on Play Developer Console to do so.

So to answer your main question, while you can track the overall flow of your purchase feature in debug mode on your app, you won't be able to test a successful transaction while using the debugger.